# Search for files with specific ending

Tags: linux, terminal

I have a folder on my Ubuntu machine with a large amount of images in it.

How would I find all the files which have a certain ending, such as `_some_ending.tif`?

Comment: Will suite [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) more

Comment: @oleksii Should just remove the ubuntu tag and replace it with bash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In only the current directory :

```
ls *_some_ending.tif
```

To recurse directories :

```
find . -name "*_some_ending.tif"
```